# How to add double precision in mongoDB schema validation?

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema, php-mongodb

I wanna make schema validation in mongoDB for double precision which modify value.

Like if I insert or update a double value 12.1111 it will save as 12.11 like we can do this in mysql DOUBLE(10, 2) when creating table.

I got answer like these but I wanna do it in schema if possible

```
$roundedDouble = round($double, 2);

$document = ['double' => $roundedDouble];

$collection->insertOne($document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add validation with `multipleOf` in your JSON Schema defintion

| Keyword | Type | Definition | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| multipleOf | numbers | number | Field must be a multiple of this value |

something like

```json
{
    "validator": {
        "$jsonSchema": {
            "bsonType": "object",
            "properties": {
                "score": {
                    "bsonType": "double",
                    "multipleOf": 0.01,
                    "description": "a double value with 2 points of precision"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```